# C++ mid-function hook: get register values and jump back [x86 assembly on windows]

Tags: c++, windows, x86, hook, inline-assembly

There is an int value in register `EBP` and a string in `EBX`. I need to get the values from these registers in my own function, do some operations on them and finally jump back some code below.

[image: ollydbg jmp start]

I do a `JMP` at `0x46AA17` to my function called `JmpHook`.

```
 void JmpHook()
 {
      char *mystring;
      _asm mov mystring, ebx

      printf("value: %s", mystring);

      _asm
      {
          jmp       [0x46AA87]
      }
  }
```

As you can see, I am trying to move the string at `EBX` into `mystring` and at the end jump back to `0x46AA87` which is located some lines below my `JMP JmpHook`.

`printf` is being called and mystring being output but all this seems very untidy in OllyDbg. I am also unable to get `EBP` as it's being overwritten at the beginning of `JmpHook`(Saw that in OllyDbg). The `JMP` at the end of `JmpHook` also does not work:
[image: ollydbg error]

So my question is how to properly jump to my own function, save the two registers there in variables and then after some operations jump back to the original code.

Thank you!

Comment: Which particular architecture/environment is this??

Comment: 32bit assembly on windows. Why did you vote it down?

Comment: _'Why did you vote it down?'_ Because you missed to clarify some essential points in your question.

Comment: Ah, this helps, thanks. If nothing is specified, it's obviously x86 asm...

Comment: Yes! There aren't even any 64bit registers in my screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value of the last EBP from the stack.

It is the first value that is pushed on the stack when you call your function. If I am not mistaken it will be at [EBP].

As for the jump, can you make it so that instead of jumping to the hook, you call it? After the function returns the code will continue from the next address.

The reason you are getting an error is because you never reach the end of the function.
Normally a function contains a prologue and an epilogue, where stack pointers are saved and retrieved.

Prologue:

```
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
```

Epilogue:

```
pop ebp
```

Since you never reach the end of the function, the pop is not called, and your stack is corrupted.

The error you are getting with the jump is because you are jumping to a location pointed to by the memory in the address 0x46AA87. You probably wanted to jump to the address, so the brackets are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution. I put a call to my function inside my other jump which I reconstructed to a `_declspec(naked)`. I was also able to retrieve the int through [ebp]. Thanks a lot!