# Get register value by detouring specific address [x86 assembly on Windows]

Tags: c++, x86, hook, inline-assembly

What I'm trying to do is intercept a register value at a given address in a x86 asm and put it into a variable. To do that, I'm injecting a dll into my program, here it is:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
    int randomNum;
    DWORD address = 0x088AD6D; // return address (used only with JMP)

    __asm
    {
        //rewriting what I erased with my detour
        movsx eax, byte ptr ds:[esi+4]
        push ebp
        push eax

        // moving ecx to my variable
        mov randomNum, ecx
    }

    printf("number: %d\n", randomNum); // This correctly print the value I detoured


    // this part is only used if I use JMP instead of call
    __asm
    {
        JMP address // return to where the program should have been
    }

}


void DetourAddress(void* funcPtr, void* hook)
{

    // write jmp
    BYTE cmd[5] =
    { 
        0xE9, //jmp
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  //address
    };

    /*
    // write call
    BYTE cmd[5] =
    {
        0xE8, // call
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 // our function address
    };
    */

    DWORD dwProtect;

    VirtualProtect(funcPtr, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtect); // make memory writable
    DWORD offset = ((DWORD)hook - (DWORD)funcPtr - 5);  //((to)-(from)-5)
    memcpy(&cmd[1], &offset, 4); // write address into jmp
    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)funcPtr, cmd, 5, 0); // write jmp / call
    VirtualProtect(funcPtr, 5, dwProtect, NULL); // reprotect
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved  )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

        DetourAddress((void*)0x088AD68, (void*)&test);

        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        FreeConsole();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The DetourAddress function is where all the magic is supposed to happen, I write a jmp command at the address I want to detour to my test() function. The test function replicate the code that was erased and I move the ecx value into my variable randomNum. I then jmp back to where the code should have been at if I didn't detour it. In theory, it works fine, but the problem is that during my test() function, the registers value get changed and when I jmp back to the original code, not only do my program stop working as intended, but it also crashes soon enough because of access violation...

For those of you who are visual, here are what happens in ollydbg:

Step 1 (the original code):

[image]

Step 2, what it looks like after I detoured the code:

[image]

Step 3, the function test() in ollydbg:

[image]

Step 4, the jmp back to the original code:

[image]

As you can see, when we go back to the original code the registers value are completely changed which leads to all sort of problem... I'm looking for a way to prevent that.

I found this question ([C++ mid-function hook: get register values and jump back [x86 assembly on windows]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110552/c-mid-function-hook-get-register-values-and-jump-back-x86-assembly-on-window)) that is similar (or even identical...) to mine but the answer given doesn't help me. I tried using a call command instead of jmp and not only did the registers value kept being changed, but it also lead to one more problem: When I returned from my test() function, it returned in non readable memory instead of the original function...

Help please?

Comment: So the problem appears to stem from the fact that you are calling printf in the middle of your detour.  When calling functions, some registers must be preserved by the called function, and some can be overwritten.  These rules vary depending on which calling convention is used.  Perhaps you could do something else with the value (write it to a buffer?) or push/pop the registers that change before/after the printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather hook the call a few instructions down, this will allow you to correctly preserve the registers while avoiding any inline assembly all together. building the pass-though and capture would look something like (assuming it returns nothing):

```
typedef void (__stdcall * hookfn)(const char* str, DWORD dw1, DWORD dw2, DWORD dw3, DWORD dw4);

void __stdcall Intercept(const char* str, DWORD dw1, DWORD dw2, DWORD dw3, DWORD dw4)
{
    randomNum = dw1;
    printf("%d\n",randomNum);

    hookfn fn = (hookfn)((DWORD)BaseOfTargetModule + RVAOfCall);
    fn(str,dw1,dw2,dw3,dw4);
}
```

You'd use your same patching mechanism to overwrite the relative call address. Its also a good idea to account for relocation by using Base+RVA rather than a fixed virtual address.

If you still want your hook, you need to preserve all the registers, this is easily done using `PUSHAD` on entry and `POPAD` on exit (these save/restore all registers bar the flags). Also, you should only perform the instructions that you overwrote just before you jump back (but after the `POPAD`), else they can cause issues with whatever your hook might be doing.